# Do religious citizens have any effect on converting other citizens?

Tags: civilization-6

I understand that a city of a religion exerts religious pressure, which works to convert citizens of nearby cities. If over half a city's citizens convert, the city itself adopts the religion.

My question is, do individual religious citizens of cities with no official religion have any effect of converting their fellow citizens in that city? What about religious pressure at nearby cities?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Only the majority religion of a city counts here. If a city has no majority, it exerts no pressure on nearby cities. Additionally, it will exert athiest/pantheon pressure on itself when it grows, reducing the religion's share of a population.

When converting cities, it's worth doing it properly, even if that means expending multiple charges.